# json returns nothing after value changed

Tags: javascript, php, datatables

I have DataTables table with row details which are opening by clicking on row. The row details are displayed in 3 different languages which are selected by checkbox. When the row is clicked, the language is send to details.php script (langy:chLanguage) which returns json values for this selected language.

Initialy the language is set to chDe and everything is working fine until I click on another language. When the language is changed to EN or RU, or even back to DE, the returned json is empty.

index.php :

```
<h5>Language</h5>

  <input type="checkbox" id="chDe" name="languages" checked>DE
  <input type="checkbox" id="chEn" name="languages">EN
  <input type="checkbox" id="chRu" name="languages">RU

<script>

var chLanguage = "chDe";
$('input[name=languages]').click(function() {
        $('input[name="' + this.name + '"]').not(this).prop('checked', false);
        chLanguage = [];
        $('input[name=languages]:checked').each(function() {
                chLanguage.push($(this).attr('id'));
        });
        if (chLanguage == '') {
                chLanguage = 5;
        }
        $('#example').DataTable().ajax.reload();
});


function format ( rowData, row, $chLanguage ) {
// FOLLOWING CONSOLE.LOG RETURNS THE ACTUALLY SELECTED LANGUAGE CORRECTLY
        console.log("chLanguage in format function: " + chLanguage);
    var div = $('<div/>')
        .addClass( 'loading slider' )
    $.ajax( {
        url: 'scripts/details.php',
        data: {
            name: rowData[0],
            langy: chLanguage,
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'post',
        success: function ( json ) {
// FOLLOWING CONSOLE.LOG RETURNS [Object object] unless the language is changed, then it returns nothing
            console.log("json: " + json);
            var childTable = '<div id="rowdetails" class="slidera"><ul class="slider">';
            childTable = childTable.concat(
                '<div class="row rdstyle">' +
                   '<table class="detailstable detailserrors">' +
                      '<tr><td><b>Error class:</b></td><td>' + json[0].ERRTRIEDA + '</td></tr>' +
                      '<tr><td><b>Error group:</b></td><td>' + json[0].ERRSKUPINA + '</td></tr>' +
                      '<tr><td><b>Error:</b></td><td>' + json[0].ERRPOPIS + '</td></tr>' +
                    '</table>' +
                '</div>
  );
 });
}
```

details.php :

```
$language = $_POST['langy'];

if ($language == 'chDe' ) {
        $setLang = 'DE';
}else if($language == 'chEn') {
        $setLang = 'EN';
} else{$setLang = 'RU';}
```

and $setLang is used in SQL query to filter data by language.

I hope I'm not far away from working solution, because it's working already, just the language switch don't work. Sorry not to attach working sample. I don't know how to implement all these parts including mysql db and several differenct php scripts :(

Comment: Have you tried dumping out $_POST using explode or print_r to see if it contains everything you think it does?

Comment: Hi SPlatten, thanks. I'm not very familiar with PHP, but I will try it and let you know. When I added print_r($language); after $language = $_POST['langy']; in details.php, it won't open the row details, but throws no error in console or apache error.log :(

Comment: Try print_r($_POST, true);

Comment: I tried it, but I can't see any message or error.

Comment: Try prefixing the line with echo or die.

Comment: Sorry, nothing. I searched the access.log and error.log in apache and browser console. Is one of these places right, or do I have to check somewhere else?

Comment: Can you see the console?  The echo and die instructions will dump the data into the server console, if you can't then you may need to write the data to a file then view the file.

Comment: Sorry, just read your original post again, try:  console.log(print_r($_POST, true));

Comment: I'm afraid I'm missing the information where to put your command. In details.php ??

Comment: Insert it before the line $language = $_POST['langy']; in details.php, on the server (php) you should probably use echo or die().

Comment: Hi SPlatten, I'm finally able to check the value of $language when the page loaded and then when the checkbox is changed to another language. So, when the page loads, the chLanguage is set to "chDe" and everything is ok and also in the $language variable (in details.php) is the "chDe", but after click on checkbox with another language, the $language variable (details.php) is empty. Therefore the SQL select is also empty, because it returns only records with empty language, which doesn't exists.

Comment: dump the contents of $_POST and check in both cases, it may give you some idea as to whats happening.